# Toasts in AndEngine Scenes

Tags: android, andengine

I am using a scene manage and I have different classes extended from scene which are used to to display different modes.
I am getting the prob in Toasting messages.
In my Mode1 class extended from scene I want to show a toast message but it gives error that 
"Cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare()"

I tried to do this inside handler but same result. I tried to make a static handler in main class but no result.
Can any one tell me the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create toast message using following way also.

```
mainActivity.toastOnUiThread("No moves available for REDO",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 4):

The key is to run it on the UI Thread - this is what I use

```
    public void gameToast(final String msg) {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(MyMainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: but the problem is that in my Scene class extended from Scene the above code is not working. There isn't any runonuithreadmethod.

Comment: try myActivity.this.runOnUiThread() where myActivity is the name of your main activity.

Comment: just to clarify - the runOnUiThread() method is part of the Android Activity class - not anything in AndEngine, not Scene, not your SceneManager. But your main activity extends BaseGameActivity (or one of the variants provided by AndEngine) which invariably must extend the Android Activity class, so that's where the call will be hiding.

Comment: so in my scenario I cant Toast?

Comment: add the above method to your activity and you can

Answer (score 2):

in your class extending from BaseGameActivity just make a method like

```
public static void MakeToast(String Msg)
{
    message = Msg;
    Handles.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

static Handler Handles = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

        if(msg.what==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(myCxt, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
};
```

and in your scene class you will call.
    YourBaseGameActivity.MakeToast("Hello World");

message is a static String variable too.